# Nourishment of cave dwellers?

Tags: medieval, food

My world is set in a post-thermonuclear war scenario. Most life on the surface has died, but a few humans who survived in underground shelters.

Once the radiation levels reached a non-lethal level, most of these survivors returned to the surface, while a few chose to stay underground. Due to hostility between these 2 factions, my 'Dwarfs' are extinct in most places, but the northern, cold regions.

They have access to some limited pre-war technology while they mostly live on medieval standards. They mostly know how to use it, while they lack the knowledge to properly maintain or understand it.

Besides that they rarely leave their cave or interact with other species.

I struggle to find any source of food for my dwarfs but roots and mushrooms.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Read Metro 2033, there they grow  fungi from leftover biomass (though since this is a circular system there will be loss), and to close that gap through loss they grow regular vegetables with electric light.
And that's how your dwarves could sustain themselves. Some built-to-last thermonuclear generators keep cranking out electricity to fuel the vegetable growths (or hydroelectric plants from underground rivers maybe). Because with mushroom recycling you won't need that much actually new biomass

Also roots? no. how would they work?